# How to convert the mySql query into rails ORM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a following query which gives the records according to the orders priority. I want to translate this traditional mySql query into rails ORM, but I am not able to do that.
My query is as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM user_questions q
WHERE question_sequence_number IN (11,13,16,19) 
OR id IN (198,199,200,201,202)
ORDER BY (question_sequence_number IN (11,13,16,19)) DESC,
      CASE WHEN question_sequence_number IN (11,13,16,19) 
           THEN question_sequence_number
           ELSE id
      END
```

Can anybody please help me out in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I could write by myself only. The above query will be converted into the ORM in rails is as following:

```
UserQuestion.where("question_sequence_number IN (?) OR id IN (?)", [11,13,16,19], [198,199,200,201,202]).order("question_sequence_number IN (#{[11,13,16,19].join(',')}) DESC, CASE WHEN question_sequence_number IN (#{[11,13,16,19].join(',')}) THEN question_sequence_number ELSE id END" )
```

Thanks.